# I have a question regarding this scanner code in java where we use next.Line. It works for one of my code but does not work with another code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was trying to create a calculator where i prompt the user to input the first number and then the operator which is a string and finally prompt the user for the second number. When i was done inputting the value for the first prompt, the last prompt appeared together with the operator prompt and when i input the operator, it results in an error.

```
System.out.print("Enter the your first number: ");
double x = calculator.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the operator: ");
String y = calculator.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the your second number: ");
double z = calculator.nextDouble();
```

This is what i get when i run the program:

```
Enter the your first number: 5
Enter the operator: Enter the your second number: +
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at 
Flow_Of_Control.Calculator_4_function_sc_statement.main(Calculator_4_function_sc_statement.java:37)
```

It works fine when i use '.next()' but i want to know why it did not work with the .nextLine() as the code below works fine with .nextline() while the 
code above does not.

```
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String name = keyboardInput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your Age: ");    
    int age = keyboardInput.nextInt();
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Just posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextDouble()` doesn't read the new line character from the console, it is being read by `calculator.nextLine();`. You can see it in the output

> Enter the operator: Enter the your second number: +

You insert the operator to the `Enter the your second number:` request, so it read by `nextDouble()`.

A workaround would be to call `nextLine()` after calling `nextDouble()`

```
System.out.print("Enter the your first number: ");
double x = calculator.nextDouble();
calculator.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the operator: ");
String y = calculator.nextLine();
```

You can also always use `nextLine()` and convert it to the correct type

```
System.out.print("Enter the your first number: ");
double x = Double.parseDouble(calculator.nextLine());
```